# Use of #undef in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am studying a piece of code from GSL libraries and puzzled by few lines in the beginning of a header file.
I understand what #undef, #ifdef and etc. do but what I don't understand is why did they basically reset the definition of the _BEGIN_DECLS and then go on and define it again? Technically, there shouldn't be any previous definitions, right? I mean, those things are static and are not subject to changes.
Anyway, here is the excerpt from the code:

```
    #undef __BEGIN_DECLS
    #undef __END_DECLS
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    # define __BEGIN_DECLS extern "C" {
    # define __END_DECLS }
    #else
    # define __BEGIN_DECLS /* empty */
    # define __END_DECLS /* empty */
    #endif
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not allowed to `#define` a macro that is already defined unless the parameter lists and replacement lists are identical.

If `__BEGIN_DECLS` was previously defined to be replaced by something other than `extern "C" {`, the `#define __BEGIN_DECLS extern "C" {` would be invalid and the program would be ill-formed.

> Technically, there shouldn't be any previous definitions, right?

There could have been, sure.

Comment: Thanks James,
makes sense. I didn't think of other possible definitions of _BEGIN_DECLS for other purposes.

Comment: Especially since identifiers with double underscore are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Technically, there should not have been any previous definition that is different than what the header file would set, because the same file would not set `__cplusplus` for one header and `#undef` it for another

Answer (score 2):

Not really. If another library that you are calling use the same name, that would be already defined.

So, as you cannot define it over another definition, you first call `#undef` and then `#define`.

Sometimes it is appropriate to use `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`.